# Adding CSS Class To Unread Comments

Tags: theming

Hello im sure that this would be possible from my experience of drupal. I have threaded comments. People who reply to comments up the thread have their comment up next to the comment they replied to. My members seem to miss these comments when viewing the thread. Is it possible to add a css class or something so as unread comments are a differant colour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should wrap new comments in a comment-new class already, but if your theme does it differently, you could edit its comment.tpl.php or copy comment.tpl.php from the comment module to your theme and act upon the $comment->new value to wrap it differently yourself.